# Правильность постановки вопроса.Срочно.

Tags: общие-вопросы

Добрый вечер!
Принесли листок соцопроса. Меня смущает правильность постановки вопроса.

"Выезжали ли вы куда-либо___ июня?.

1.Да

2.Нет".

Разгорелся большой спор на городском форуме. Прошу помощи у профессионалов.

Comment: Тут еще и орфография хромает: куда - либо. А о чем спорили?

Comment: Это общегородской опрос (принесли с квитанцией на оплату), для подготовки города к ЧМ по футболу, транспортную структуру города собираются улучшать. Это первый пункт опроса. Меня он поставил в тупик. На месте пропуска нужно поставить число. Многие считают, что все нормально. Вот я решила спросить у профессионалов, может я придираюсь.
P.S. Орфографическая ошибка сделана мной,исправила, не сразу поняла, как редактировать.

Answer (score 1):

В целом вопрос действительно сомнительный. Если уж задавать такой, то без уточнения даты либо вписывать интересующую. Вероятно, тут косяк анкетологов

Answer (score 0):

Простите, но я не понимаю, в чем суть претензий к формулировке вопроса. Если бы на месте пропуска стояла дата, Вас по-прежнему терзали бы сомнения? Мне почему-то не кажется, что есть для таковых основания. Если после подстановки числа терзания прекращаются, то позвольте заметить, что число не изъято из предложения - оно просто не уточняется. Поправьте, если заблуждаюсь.

Answer (score 0):

А в чем, собственно,сомнения? Полностью согласен с Noir. Не вижу причин для претензий к формулировке. Кстати, с орфографией все нормально! Правильно именно куда-либо, а не куда - либо. В этом можно убедиться, заглянув в любой справочник по орфографии.

Comment: В первой версии были "куда-либо" было написано без дефиса, потом автор исправила.

Comment: Совершенно верно)